# How to pass the params in post method for datatable ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I need to pass all parameters in post method for jquery ajax call. I am explaining my existing code below.

```
 var activeSemster = $('#tblActiveSemester').DataTable();
 activeSemster.ajax.url(
   "semesterSubjectMap_db.php?type=SELECT_ACTIVE_SEMESTER&_s=" +
   session + "&course_code=" + $('#cmbActvSemCourse').val() +
   "&batch_code=&semester_status=").load();
```

Here I am passing all value in get method and I need pass those parameters in post method.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass custom params in fnServerData:

```
activeSemster = $('#tblActiveSemester').DataTable({
  "serverSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "semesterSubjectMap_db.php",
  "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
    aoData.push({"name": "type", "value": "SELECT_ACTIVE_SEMESTER"});
    aoData.push({"name": "_s", "value": session});
    aoData.push({"name": "course_code", "value": $('#cmbActvSemCourse').val()});
    // ..etc
    $.ajax({
      "dataType": 'json',
      url: sSource,
      type: "post",
      data: aoData,
      success: fnCallback
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Let me to check and confirm you.

Comment: It seems that fnServerData method is legacy. It works for 1.10.13, not sure about after that. Try this thread for latest version: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/129820/

Comment: What version of DataTables? You might need to use ajax.data option instead, as suggested in above thread.

Comment: I am using `1.10` version. Can you change your post accordingly. ?

Comment: Added some code that seemed not related to the problem. Should work up to 1.10.13. If it doesn't, then what's the result / error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171901/discussion-between-subhra-and-konservin).

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code worked for me,

```
var tasks_table = jQuery('#tasks-tab-table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url: ajax_url,
        "data": function (d) {
            d.action = "getTaskTabToDoTabTableData";
            d.post_per_page = tasks_post_per_page;
        },
        "error": function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500]. Try after some time!');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        },
        "success": function (res) {
            var tasks_todo_table = jQuery('#tasks-tab-table').DataTable();
            tasks_todo_table.rows.add(res.data).draw(true);
            //your code
         },
         "error": function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        console.log('Internal Server Error [500]. Try after some time!');
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        console.log('Time out error.');
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                },
            });
            //set total tasks and email pages - close
        }
    },
    "sDom": "ltp",
    "aaSorting": [1, 'desc'],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}],
    "paging": false,
});
```

Hope this will helps you.